# Getting each model from a Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm convinced this is a very easy fix, but none of the posts I've found so far seem to have addressed this directly: how do I loop over a collection to get each model?

The first method I'm trying to use is underscore's each method. Here is my call and function:

```
collection_var.each(paintThings);
```

and here is my function:

```
function paintThings() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.model);
            var thing_type = this.model.get("type"),
                thing_other = this.model.get("otherAttribute");

                console.log(this.model);
                console.log(thing_type);
                console.log(thing_other);
        }
```

Right now, this comes out as undefined, and this.model errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined
```

I know the answer is simple, but it's driving me crazy! I'm new to underscore. Can anyone here help? I'm also open to other non-underscore methods if they are faster/better.

I also tried this:

```
 for (var i = 0, l = collection_var.length; i < l; i++) {
            console.log(collection_var[i]);
 }
```

but that's not giving me what I want either.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First method: use the `models` property of your collection:

```
var myModel
for(var i=0; i<myCollection.length; i++) {
  myModel = myCollection.models[i];
}
```

Second method is with the `each` method:

```
myCollection.each(function(model, index, [context]) {...});
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks for posting both options. Your solution is more elegant than mine because it doesn't need the function to be defined beforehand. Thanks again!

Comment: @streetlight it would depend. Declaring the function elsewhere may give you a more structure code. That was just the lazy way of showing the solution ;)

Comment: @Loamhoof . is it underscore each method ?? if yes then where is `_` sign . please let me know . thank  you

Comment: @Mahi Pretty much all the underscore methods can be used directly as Collections methods. See http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-147.

Answer (score 3):

Iterating over every model of a collection eg. as give by backbone.js is

```
books.each(function(book) {
  book.publish();
});
```

In your case it should be something like this

```
collection_var.each(function(paintThing){
    console.log(paintThing);
    var thing_type = this.model.get("type"),
        thing_other = this.model.get("otherAttribute");

    console.log(paintThing);
    console.log(thing_type);
    console.log(thing_other);
});
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `collection_var.models.each(paintThings)`. That should give you direct access to the models of a collection.

Comment: No, the underscore method are meant to be used with Backbone's Collections, not with the Arrays (though it would work, but that's not how it's meant to be used).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, stupid error! I just had to pass an extra parameter to the function so I can touch the model.

Like this:

```
function paintThings(thing) {
    //returns model
    console.log(thing);
        var thing_type = thing.get("type"),
            thing_other = thing.get("otherAttribute");

            //These all respond directly
            console.log(thing);
            console.log(thing_type);
            console.log(thing_other);
    }
```

I'm still going to review all answers and accept the most elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

I used underscores map.

```
docs = Backbone.Collection.extend();

this.subViews = _.map(docs.models, function(doc) {
    return new DocView({ model: doc });
}, this);
```